# ADB cannot list my device when my nexus 6p is in recovery mode

Tags: android, linux, macos, adb, fastboot

I want to update my nexus 6p to Nougat (manually OTA), so I went to settings to activate dev options and checked debbuging mode.
When my phone is full booted and I run this command on terminal **adb devices** it list my device, but when I run **adb reboot recovery** and I get into recovery mode if try to run **adb devices** adb doesn't show my device and if I try to **apply update from adb** it says:

**MYs-MacBook-Pro:Android etomas$ adb sideload angler-ota-mtc20f-5a1e93e9.zip
loading: 'angler-ota-mtc20f-5a1e93e9.zip'
error: no devices/emulators found**

So far I've tried:

- oem unlocking;
- when in recovery mode run **adb kill-server** disconnect and connect my usb    cable and then run **adb devices**;
- force to add my device to adb_usb.ini **sudo echo 0x18d1 >> /Users/etomas/Library/Android/adb_usb.ini**;
- to unload this **sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext**;
- reboot my phone my laptop;
- updating my sdk platform to the latest version 24.0.2;

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
I'm already running android studio on my laptop;

**My nexus 6p**
Android Version:6.0.1
Android Security Patch Level: August 5, 2016;
BaseBand Version: angler-03.61;
Kernel Version: 3.10.73-g909746b
Build number: mtc20f

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting your usb cable? In recovery a different device-id is used and therefore you need to connect once in recovery mode.

Comment: @Elijan9 yes check "when in recovery mode run adb kill-server disconnect and connect my usb cable and then run adb devices;"

Comment: Hi everyone, i could get ride of this problem after installing Nexus Tools from https://github.com/corbindavenport/nexus-tools, rebooting my laptop and after entering the recovery mode just had to run **adb kill-server** and then disconnect the usb cable from the laptop and connect again i run **adb devices** and my device was listed.

Comment: This question should be in https://android.stackexchange.com/, wouldn't you mind if I migrate it there?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

You need to wipe the cache partition and then go to the recovery menu.

1. Boot into recovery:

   `adb reboot recovery`

You will see the Google logo for a few seconds followed by a green android on his back with
“No command” underneath.

2. Press and hold Power, then tap Volume Up once, then release Power.
   You should see Android Recovery menu (yellow with device info, firmware build version, keys).
   NOTE: If your device starts rebooting at this point, your only recourse is to contact your
   place of purchase about a warranty replacement or repair.
3. Remove the USB cable between the Computer and the Nexus 6P (maybe not needed but recommended).
4. Tap volume down to select "Wipe cache partition" (confirm with power).
5. Plug USB cable back.
6. Finally select "Apply Update from ADB" and run it.

   `adb sideload lineage-15.1-20200204-nightly-angler-signed.zip`
7. Reboot the system.

Credits: rfdesign21, see https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/help/stock-nexus-6p-wont-flash-ota-t3468928, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6x7k-VkpUJRjl6WjRhVmdXU0E/view